# Exception 401 during export to Microsoft Exchange 2007

Tags: exchangewebservices

I have a vb.net application that communicates with Exchange 2000 & 2003 using WebDAV, but it does not work with Exchange 2007 SP2

Test Environment and configuration

1. Windows 2003, AD and domain controller, Exchange 2007 SP2
2. With Public Folders
3. OWA can be accessed with a browser
4. https://myserver.com/public/Contacts can be access through browser
5. The credential used by the vb.net application is NetworkCredential
6. Using administrator credentials

When I run my code it throws exception 401 unathorized. Using EWS, it works. At this stage, I don't want to convert the code to EWS. Has anyone got a solution?

Answer (score 1):

are you using the correct URL for SoapUI?

Point it to https://server/ews/exchange.asmx. Replace server with the dns name of your Exchange server.